# Problems with nomenclature in Elsiver cls elsarticle, with sublime in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elsarticle, sublime-text, nomencl

I've just face with a problem with `\usepackage{nomencl}` environment.
I am using the Elsiver article cls, elsarticle.cls, and want to insert a nomenclature for all the abbreviations.

I'm following the instruction from:

-- [How to add “Nomenclature” in “elsarticle” (2-column format) through TexMaker](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20555)

--  [elsarticle | Custom Nomenclature Formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252118/how-to-add-nomenclature-in-elsarticle-2-column-format-through-texmaker/252126)

The platform I use is Sublime 2, with LaTex tools package.

However, I still cannot show the nomenclature in my final pdfs.
It just returns an empty frame without any items in it. Please see the following figure:

[image]

Could anybody help me out of this dilemma?
Thanks very much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you remember to run `makeindex`: [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27824)